# Extract a directory from tar archive using ansible unarchive

Tags: ansible, tar

I'd like to extract one directory from tar file.

In Linux OS for install directory unpacking - I simply do:

```
tar -xvf ingres.tar install
```

For ansible I've tried:

```
unarchive:
  remote_src: yes
  src: /ingres/ingres.tar
  dest: /ingres
  extra_opts:
    - "install"
```

But it doesn't work of course. Any idea?

Comment: if you don't have too much top-level entries you could use the option `exclude:` or use directly the `shell:` module

Comment: I'm not sure if content of top-level directory is always the same. I know I can use `shell:`, just wonder if it is possible without

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The GNU tar command has an option to select archive members: `--add-file`. [Section 6.2 of the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC107) mentions it:

> If a file name begins with dash (`-`), precede it with `--add-file` option to prevent it from being treated as an option.

However, it works for other files too, which means you can specify this option in the `extra_opts` of your task to select file(s) or directories to extract:

```
unarchive:
  remote_src: yes
  src: /ingres/ingres.tar
  dest: /ingres
  extra_opts:
    - "--add-file"
    - "install"
```

Comment: Great! Works as expected! Thanks

Comment: You're welcome! I was looking for an answer to the same question. Unfortunately this does make the task less portable to different types of archives, as `unzip` has different command-line options.

Comment: Yes, indeed, but for me is enough, I'll use only gtar in this case. Solution is perfect!